# Send Password if user forgets

Tags: asp-classic

I'm working on a project with asp and i have a section of where a user forgets his or her password she enters her email and if it's valid it sends the password. Now the problem is, its able to check if the email is in the database alright and sends the mail, but can't send the password along.

```
<%

'Check if the form has been processed
If Request.Form("process")="true" Then
  'Check the recordset for a valid record


  If Not rs_user.Eof Then
    'Valid record, so proceed with the email
    Call sSendReminder (rs_user("email"), rs_user("password"))
    Response.Write "Your password has been sent to your inbox. If you don't find it in your mail box, check your junk mail folder" 


     dim sName, sEmail, sMessage
    dim oCdoMail, oCdoConf, sConfURL


    sEmail = Request.Form("email")


        Set oCdoMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        Set oCdoConf = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

        sConfURL = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"



        with oCdoConf
            .Fields.Item(sConfURL & "sendusing") = 2
            .Fields.Item(sConfURL & "smtpserver") = "smptserveraddress.com"
            .Fields.Item(sConfURL & "smtpserverport") = 25
            .Fields.Update


        end with

        with oCdoMail
            .From = "noreply@sample.com"
            .To = sEmail
            .Subject = "Password Recovery from samplesite"
            .TextBody = "Your password is: " & password
            .HTMLBody = "Your password is: " & password
            .Configuration = oCdoConf
            .Send
        end with

        Set oCdoConf = Nothing
        Set oCdoMail = Nothing


  Else
    'Not a valid record
    Response.Write "Sorry, no email was found."
  End If
End If 

        Sub sSendReminder(email, password)

End Sub
```

%>

Comment: response.write rs_user("password") above Call sSendReminder. Do you see a value?

Comment: come again. i don't get you

Comment: i get you now, with the response.write its able to write the password on the page but can't send in the body of the mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the above code the exact code you are running?

If so, you need to move the

```
Sub sSendReminder(email, password)
```

above

```
dim sName, sEmail, sMessage
```

You also need to move those "end if" statements outside the sub.

Your code runs (I think) because it is technically correct, but it doesn't run like you think it should because your sub is actually blank.

Correct code would look like this:

```html
<%

'Check if the form has been processed
If Request.Form("process")="true" Then
  'Check the recordset for a valid record


If Not rs_user.Eof Then
    'Valid record, so proceed with the email
    Call sSendReminder (rs_user("email"), rs_user("password"))
    Response.Write "Your password has been sent to your inbox. If you don't find it in your mail box, check your junk mail folder" 
 Else
    'Not a valid record
    Response.Write "Sorry, no email was found."
  End If
End If 
 
 
 
Sub sSendReminder(email, password)

     dim sName, sEmail, sMessage
    dim oCdoMail, oCdoConf, sConfURL


    sEmail = Request.Form("email")


        Set oCdoMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        Set oCdoConf = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

        sConfURL = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"



        with oCdoConf
            .Fields.Item(sConfURL & "sendusing") = 2
            .Fields.Item(sConfURL & "smtpserver") = "smptserveraddress.com"
            .Fields.Item(sConfURL & "smtpserverport") = 25
            .Fields.Update


        end with

        with oCdoMail
            .From = "noreply@sample.com"
            .To = sEmail
            .Subject = "Password Recovery from samplesite"
            .TextBody = "Your password is: " & password
            .HTMLBody = "Your password is: " & password
            .Configuration = oCdoConf
            .Send
        end with

        Set oCdoConf = Nothing
        Set oCdoMail = Nothing
End Sub %>
```

Comment: thanks man, it worked. Jesus Bless you beyond your wildest imagination